# Sitecore membership maintain user preference data

Tags: sitecore, membership

We have developed a public website using Sitecore. There are public login users who can mark items(articles) as flagged and add notes for later references as they browse through the site. At the moment we are maintaining public login users using Sitecore items in master database.
And each time a login user flag an article and add a note we add a child item to user item in content tree and save note content there.
We have taken up a decision to move in to Sitecore membership module so we can use it's profile information features etc...

The problem we are facing is exporting these child note items. What will be a suitable way to do this using Sitecore membership module?

We have thought of keeping the same user structure in master database and linking membership users to those user items(foreign key like approach) and refer those notes from there. Any thoughts regarding this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently following best practice for two reasons:

1. You are managing front-facing logins in the master database and not Membership, however you are moving to Membership which is a good decision. Refer to the [Security API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx) for this.
2. You are storing user-generated content (UGC) in the master database which means you're making the full round-trip to your CM instance. I recommend you update this with a custom extra database to store UGC. It could be as simple as a table mapping a username (e.g. `domain\username`), to an associated content item by its GUID (in the "web" DB), and the actual UGC (the notes from the user). You could create a light-weight Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL data access layer to work with this extra DB.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the flag/note items to be under the article item itself, and have the user ID (Sitecore User have a Guid id) stored as a field in the flag/note items.

If you want, you can extend Sitecore membership provider or create your own membership provider by implementing [.NET MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx), this way you can store the flags and notes outside Sitecore master database, this way might requires [Security API Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx)